# Struct store large chunk of data

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a data file with millions of rows and I wanted to read that and store in a struct.

```
public struct Sample
{
    public int A;
    public DateTime B;
}

Sample[] sample = new Sample[];
```

This definition gives me this error "**Wrong number of indicies inside[]; expected 1**"

How do I store data in struct (**with less memory usage**)? Array is that best of something else?

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\test.csv"));
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    var values = line.Split(';');
}
```

Comment: You need to specify a size for the array.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I am looping through a file. don't know the exact size!

Answer (score 0):

In order to allocate an array, you need to specify how many elements it holds. That's what the error is telling you.

If you don't know the size, you can use `List<T>` which will grow as needed. Internally `List<T>` is implemented using `T[]` which means that from a look-up stand point it acts like an array. However, the work of reallocating larger arrays as needed is handled by `List<T>`.